# why is pandas.to_datetime() not changing dtype?

Tags: pandas

**UPDATE**

I believed the MRE in my original question to be adequate, but it was not.  I have since made a bunch of changes to my code that ultimately resolved the issue, and when I went back to create a workable MRE, I was unable to.

In short, I don't know what exactly I did to produce the original issue.

Originally there was a `.concat()` function called that created the basis for `filtered_df` but that doesn't seem to be the culprit.

At this point, this is considered resolved, but unsure whether the best course is to delete the question or let it sit, so I'll let it sit for now.

To close this off, below is an unsuccessful attempt to recreate the original issue for nothing more than context and background.

```
import pandas
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({"id": [75979], "symbol": ["USDCAD"], "time": ["2022-11-06 19:11:00-05:00"], "open": [1], "high": [1], "low": [1], "close": [1], "volume": [None]})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({"id": [75980], "symbol": ["USDCAD"], "time": ["2022-11-06 19:12:00-05:00"], "open": [2], "high": [2], "low": [2], "close": [2], "volume": [None]})
df = pandas.concat([df1, df2])
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df

      id  symbol                       time  open  high  low  close volume
0  75979  USDCAD  2022-11-06 19:11:00-05:00     1     1    1      1   None
1  75980  USDCAD  2022-11-06 19:12:00-05:00     2     2    2      2   None
```

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   id      2 non-null      int64 
 1   symbol  2 non-null      object
 2   time    2 non-null      object
 3   open    2 non-null      int64 
 4   high    2 non-null      int64 
 5   low     2 non-null      int64 
 6   close   2 non-null      int64 
 7   volume  0 non-null      object
dtypes: int64(5), object(3)
memory usage: 256.0+ bytes
```

```
df["time"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["time"])
df

      id  symbol                       time  open  high  low  close volume
0  75979  USDCAD  2022-11-06 19:11:00-05:00     1     1    1      1   None
1  75980  USDCAD  2022-11-06 19:12:00-05:00     2     2    2      2   None
      id  symbol                      time  open  high  low  close volume
0  75979  USDCAD 2022-11-06 19:11:00-05:00     1     1    1      1   None
1  75980  USDCAD 2022-11-06 19:12:00-05:00     2     2    2      2   None
```

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype                                 
---  ------  --------------  -----                                 
 0   id      2 non-null      int64                                 
 1   symbol  2 non-null      object                                
 2   time    2 non-null      datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-300)]
 3   open    2 non-null      int64                                 
 4   high    2 non-null      int64                                 
 5   low     2 non-null      int64                                 
 6   close   2 non-null      int64                                 
 7   volume  0 non-null      object                                
dtypes: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-300)](1), int64(5), object(2)
memory usage: 256.0+ bytes
```

**ORIGINAL**

I'm trying to convert the `time` column in this dataframe to a timezone aware and localized `datetime64` like `dtype`, but the conversion isn't working:

```
print(f'1:\n{filtered_df.tail(1)}\ndtype: {filtered_df["time"].dtypes}')
filtered_df["time"] = pandas.to_datetime(filtered_df["time"])
print(f'2:\n{filtered_df.tail(1)}\ndtype: {filtered_df["time"].dtypes}')

#
1:
       id  symbol                       time     open     high      low    close volume
23  75979  USDCAD  2022-11-06 19:11:00-05:00  1.35102  1.35113  1.35102  1.35114   None
dtype: object
2:
       id  symbol                       time     open     high      low    close volume
23  75979  USDCAD  2022-11-06 19:11:00-05:00  1.35102  1.35113  1.35102  1.35114   None
dtype: object
```

Done this way, it works:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"id": [75979], "symbol": ["USDCAD"], "time": ["2022-11-06 19:11:00-05:00"], "open": [1.35102], "high": [1.3513], "low": [1.35102], "close": [1.35114], "volume": [None]})
print(f'pre: {df["time"].dtypes}')
df["time"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["time"])
print(f'post: {df["time"].dtypes}')
print(df)

#
pre: object
post: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-300)]
      id  symbol                      time     open    high      low    close  volume
0  75979  USDCAD 2022-11-06 19:11:00-05:00  1.35102  1.3513  1.35102  1.35114    None
```

I'm having a hard time understanding why one works and one doesn't.

Comment: Do you mean that `filtered_df.loc[:, "time"] = ...` is the way that doesn't work? This would be expected as `loc` on a slice doesn't change the dtypes

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear.  `filtered_df.loc[:, "time"] = ...` does not work either.  I have removed that from the original question, and also attempted to make the question more clear as to the method that works.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example of the non-working case

Comment: Indeed.   However it seems now I'm unable to reproduce the original issue in an attempt to produce a MRE.  I've updated the question in that regard.

Comment: If you're unable to reproduce, it might have been due to a mistake you did once and which will never occur. I suggest to move on and start a new question if this ever happens again ;)

Comment: 100%.  Just adding context to the additional question.  Not sure what the best thing to do is - delete the question or just add context so hopefully I don't get too much flack :)